# Cannot convert from object to System.ValueType

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to implement `IsNumeric` method from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netframework-4.5://). But passing an array value like this `Utility.IsNumeric(arrayCsvValues[i])` gives me the error

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.ValueType'  DataSetConsoleApplication   \DataSetConsoleApplication\Program.cs

This is the method.

```
   public static bool IsNumeric(ValueType value)
   {
      return (value is Byte ||
              value is Int16 ||
              value is Int32 ||
              value is Int64 ||
              value is SByte ||
              value is UInt16 ||
              value is UInt32 ||
              value is UInt64 ||
              value is BigInteger ||
              value is Decimal ||
              value is Double ||
              value is Single);
   }
```

I am working with .NET Framework 4.5.2 Console Application. Please help.

PS Edit:

Sorry, so I read this from MS Docs

> .... or to permit a method to handle a number of **different value types**.

and (sadly) figured that the method was going to accept variables with any type as in `String s` or `int S`. Answer about reference type and value type cleared everything up for me.  Downvotes well deserved.

Comment: Your error is pretty clear, are you passing it an object or a ValueType?

Comment: The error is not with your method, but it's due to the fact that you're not passing a `ValueType` object as an argument.

Comment: The error is clearly explaining to you that your `arrayCsvValues[]` has elements of type `object`, which is not `ValueType`. What part do you not understand? What are you actually asking here? Why are you even using `ValueType` as the parameter type in the first place?

Comment: show the declaration of arrayCsvValues

Comment: you can simply change the declaration to say `IsNumeric(Object value)`

Comment: @PeterDuniho my question edit should get you a laugh and answer your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code only works when you pass it a value type. The `object` you're trying to pass is a reference type, so the compiler forbids you to use that as an argument:

> [MSDN: System.ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> [...] can be used as a parameter in method calls to restrict possible arguments to value types instead of all objects

So you should just change the parameter type from `ValueType` to `object`, which would make this code work for any argument type and still execute the desired behavior.

But from the variables and code it looks like you're trying to do something else entirely. Are you looking for `decimal.TryParse()`?

Comment: I think your explanation is slightly off: `ValueType` is always a reference type too, so that doesn't explain why you can't pass an `object`.

Comment: MSDN's quote looks wrong too. As `ValueType` itself is a reference type, the quote is saying `void f(ValueType v) {} void g(ValueType v) { f(v); }` is invalid, but as I'm sure you agree and as a quick check will show, this does in fact work. The reason the OP's code is rejected is simply the general rule that you can't pass in a variable of base class type (in this case `object`) to a method expecting a derived class type (in this case `ValueType`).

Comment: "or to permit a method to handle a number of different value types."  I read this at the end of a long work day and figured that the ValueType takes in any and all reference values while ignoring the type. Forgot the basics.